# How to convert a saved_model.pb to EvalSavedModel?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-model-analysis

I was going through the `tensorflow-model-analysis` documentation evaluating TensorFlow models. The getting started guide talks about a special SavedModel called the `EvalSavedModel`.

Quoting the getting started guide:

> This EvalSavedModel contains additional information which allows TFMA
>   to compute the same evaluation metrics defined in your model in a
>   distributed manner over a large amount of data, and user-defined
>   slices.

My question is how can I convert an already existing `saved_model.pb` to an `EvalSavedModel`?

Answer (score 0):

`EvalSavedModel` is exported as SavedModel message, thus there is no need in such conversion.

`EvalSavedModel` uses `SavedModelBuilder` under the hood. It populates the estimator graph with several placeholders, creates some additional metric collections. Later on, it performs simple `SavedModelBuilder` procedure.

Source - https://github.com/tensorflow/model-analysis/blob/master/tensorflow_model_analysis/eval_saved_model/export.py#L228

P.S. I suppose you want to run `model-analysis` on your model, exported by `SavedModelBuilder`. Since `SavedModel` doesn't have neither metric nodes nor related collections, which are created in `EvalSavedModel`, it's useless to do so - `model-analysis` just simply couldn't find any metric related to your estimator.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have `saved_model.pb` generated, either by using `tf.saved_model.simple_save` or `tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder`or by `estimator.export_savedmodel`.

If my understanding is correct, then, you are exporting Training and Inference Graphs to `saved_model.pb`.

The Point you mentioned from the Guide of TF Org Website states that, **in addition to Exporting Training Graph, we need to Export Evaluation Graph as well. That is called *EvalSavedModel*.**

The Evaluation Graph comprises the Metrics for that Model, so that you can Evaluate the Model's performance using Visualizations.

Before we Export `EvalSaved` Model, we should prepare `eval_input_receiver_fn`, similar to `serving_input_receiver_fn`.

We can mention other functionalities as well, like, if you want the Metrics to be defined in a Distributed Manner or if we want to Evaluate our Model using Slices of Data, rather than the Entire Dataset. Such Options can be mentioned in `eval_input_receiver_fn`.

Then we can Export the `EvalSavedModel` using the Code below:

```
tfma.export.export_eval_savedmodel(estimator=estimator,export_dir_base=export_dir,
  eval_input_receiver_fn=eval_input_receiver_fn)
```